# Como centralizar ambos?

Tags: flutter

Estou aprendendo flutter agora, e estou fazendo este app bem simple e gostaria de saber como posso centralizar esses 2 widgets no centro e independente do tamanho do numero sempre ficar centralizado, tentei de vários modos mas não consigo de jeito nenhum, segue o código:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Isto tudo esta dentro de uma Column

```
Row(children: [
   Expanded(
      child: RotatedBox(
                 quarterTurns: 3,
                 child: Text(
                     "Pessoas", 
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white, fontSize: 40.0),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          "$countPeople",
                          style:
                              TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 150.0),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                      ]),
```

Answer (score -2):

Se voce quer centralizar no centro, pode usar da tela pode utilizar a propriedade mainAxisAlign, mas se quer que os dois items com alturas diferentes fiquem centralizados um com o outro, utilize cross-axis-center.
Eu não entendi direito sua pergunta, se não for isso, adicione mais informações para que eu possa te jaudar.

Comment: Desculpa por não explicar muito bem, mas era realmente isso que você falou, eu estava colocando isso em outra parte por isso não estava conseguindo, mas obrigado pela ajuda.